# Custom web part properties

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a custom web part, and if a user clicks on Edit web part, the properties pane in IE 11 appears and disappears, so sort of flickers.

In IE 8 it works fine.

Comment: First step: check on other browsers (firefox and chrome at least)
Second step: check on identical browser versions on a second machine

do you get the same results on both machines?
do you get the same flicker on up-to-date versions of chrome and firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2459850) simple fix worked for me.